# how to add watermark to an image nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, loopbackjs

How to add watermark to an image in nodejs. I am using loopback framework and I want to add a watermark to every image uploaded,I tried a couple of image processing modules but couldnt implement a watermark.

I tried the image-watermark library with the code :

```
watermark.embedWatermark('./server/storage/images/img_hkd.jpg', { 'text': 'sample watermark' });
```

But I am getting this error : Error: spawn identify ENOENT

Comment: this worked for me https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-watermark

Comment: I tried this, but I am getting this error :"spawn identify ENOENT"

Comment: It might be using a directory which might not be available.

Comment: the image exists in the given path, I checked it. If image is not available, it gives an image not found error

Answer (score 8):

Instead of `watermark` use `jimp` module. It worked for me.

```js
let imgActive = 'active/image.jpg';

Jimp.read('raw/originalimage.png')
      .then((tpl) => tpl.clone().write(imgActive))
      .then(() => Jimp.read(imgActive))
      .then((tpl) =>
          Jimp.read('raw/logo.png').then((logoTpl) => {
              logoTpl.opacity(0.2)
              return tpl.composite(logoTpl, 512, 512, [Jimp.BLEND_DESTINATION_OVER])
          }),
      )
      .then((tpl) => tpl.write('raw/watermark.png'))
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a package, I've used imaginary without any issue.

```
//Install
npm install imaginary --save

//Import 
var fs = require('fs')
var imaginary = require('imaginary')
var serverUrl = 'localhost:8080'

imaginary('myImage.jpg')
  .server(serverUrl)
  .watermark({ text: 'copyright' })
  .on('error', function (err) {
    console.error('Cannot resize the image:', err)
  })
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('markedImage.jpg'))
```

https://github.com/h2non/node-imaginary

Comment: Hey,thanks for helping out... what is the purpose of the serverurl ? And when I try this, it is doing a POST /watermark?text=copyright and the server is returning : Error: Invalid server response: 404

Comment: Too late to be here, can we specify the position of watermarks and its colors and opacity as optional setting?

Answer (score 2):

Package sharp can do this, and it works for two images or one image and text with font and other style, rotating and blurring, for reference

watermark an image with a logo：
const sharp = require("sharp");

```
async function compositeImages() {
  try {
    await sharp("underwater.png")
      .composite([
        {
          input: "sammy-transparent.png",
          top: 50,
          left: 50,
        },
      ])
      .toFile("sammy-underwater.png");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

compositeImages()

Adding Text on an Image：

```
const sharp = require("sharp");

async function addTextOnImage() {
  try {
    const width = 750;
    const height = 483;
    const text = "Sammy the Shark";

    const svgImage = `
    <svg width="${width}" height="${height}">
      <style>
      .title { fill: #001; font-size: 70px; font-weight: bold;}
      </style>
      <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" class="title">${text}</text>
    </svg>
    `;
    const svgBuffer = Buffer.from(svgImage);
    const image = await sharp("sammy.png")
      .composite([
        {
          input: svgBuffer,
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
        },
      ])
      .toFile("sammy-text-overlay.png");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

addTextOnImage();
```

reference: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-process-images-in-node-js-with-sharp